# Reference count for a handle instead of a pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, handle

C++11 introduces smart pointers like `std::shared_ptr`. The class stores a pointer and a reference counter. When the reference counter hits zero, a callback (deleter) is called. My question is whether C++11 has an easy way to use the reference counter of `std::shared_ptr` without the pointer.

I use a c-style library which gives me an integer as handle. I want to create a class to wrap the handle. I would like to avoid the indirection with `std::shared_ptr` while I want to have some type of reference counting to close the handle when it is not needed anymore. If you can create and destroy the handle with `createHandle` and `destroyHandle` respectively, I think it could look like this:

```
class WrapperClass
{
public:
    WrapperClass() :
        mHandle(createHandle(), &destroyHandle)
    {
    }
private:
    shared_data<int> mHandle;
}
```

or

```
class WrapperClass
{
public:
    WrapperClass() :
        mHandle(createHandle()),
        mRefCount([this](){destroyHandle(mHandle);})
    {
    }
private:
    int mHandle;
    reference_counter mRefCount;
}
```

---

Another problem with this is that I'm not sure if it is possible to have working specifiers like `const`. I mean things like that it is not possible to remove the `const`-specifier without using casts. I don't see any way to do it.

Comment: I wonder whether you could strong-arm shared_ptr in doing that. You'd probably write a trivial wrapper class for the (presumably int) handle, just to have a custom type, then define your own custom operator free() for that class which either does nothing or possibly disposes of the handle, but has nothing to do with the free store. It's probably saner to write your own shared_resource class for that; but the devil may be in the detail of getting that absolutely correct.

Comment: If you promise to yourself to never store the integer value in an `int`, then you could make a simple wrapper with an implicit conversion operator to `int`. The promise is there to prevent you from taking out the value without reference counting, whilst still allowing you to use it as a function argument wherever the library expects an `int` descriptor. The wrapper class will be like a RAII class.

Comment: @MicroVirus instead of promises better write warpper class functions for all C API functions

Comment: Other possibilities: the handle is an index or key in some data structure, and when the count hits zero, you delete the object from the data structure.  You’d have to write this yourself, though.

Comment: this is a dupe I've seen it before

Comment: @PeterSchneider If I understand you right, you mean that I could create a class where the *this*-pointer is the handle. Something that cause that if I would write `auto x = new Wrapper();`, x would be the handle (reinterpreted as pointer). I technically like the idea but I do not think that this is a *good* solution. It also cause Problems if someone think he doesn't have to share the instace und simply writes `Wrapper x;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some precautions you can try using original shared_ptr for this task:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int create_handle() {
    std::cout << "alloc\n";
    return 42;
}

void delete_handle(int handle)
{
    std::cout << "delete " << handle << "\n";
}


class Wrapper
{
public:
    Wrapper():
        _d(Wrapper::create_handle(), &Wrapper::delete_handle)
    {}

    int value()
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(_d.get());
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<void> _d;

    static void* create_handle()
    {
        static_assert(sizeof(create_handle()) <= sizeof(void*), "can't fit");
        static_assert(alignof(create_handle()) <= sizeof(void*), "can't align");
        return reinterpret_cast<void*>(static_cast<uintptr_t>(::create_handle()));
    }

    static void delete_handle(void* handle)
    {
        return ::delete_handle(reinterpret_cast<unintptr_t>(handle));
    }
};

int main()
{
    Wrapper w;
    std :: cout << w.value();
}
```

I believe you must be sure your handle can be represented as pointer (matching size and align). Then you can apply `reinterpret_cast` black magic. As you basically just convert `int` to pointer and back using reinterpret cast, but never dereference pointer, it should be safe

Comment: Cast by value and not by reference, even then it's not guaranteed to work, although it may do on many systems.

Comment: @NeilKirk, do you mean void* -> int conversion? It doesn't work even with my Ubuntu. And what is your reasoning?

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(ptr)` is the correct way to convert a pointer to an integer.

Comment: @NeilKirk, so, like this?

Comment: Assuming `uintptr_t` is large enough to hold all int values, yes. You can use `std::numeric_limits` to check that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I also thought about this possibility but I don't like to abuse the classes like this. I hoped that there were some other possibility but It doesn't seems so.